# How to cluster Google Maps in Xamarin Forms

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.forms, markerclusterer

I'm trying to cluster markers on Google Map in my xamarin forms application.
Here's my model:

```
public class MapModel
{
    public Field[] Fields { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Node[] Nodes { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
}

public class Node
{
    public float Long { get; set; }
    public float Lat { get; set; }
}
```

And here is service that I use to get values of longitudes and latitudes

```
class MapService
    {
        public static async Task<MapModel> GetMapData(string token, string lngCode)
        {
            try
            {
                MapModel mapModels = new MapModel();
                string url = DataURL.BASE_URL + "agronetmobile/mapdata?lngCode=" + lngCode;
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                    using (HttpResponseMessage message = await client.GetAsync(url))
                    {
                        if (message.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            string rawResponse = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            mapModels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MapModel>(rawResponse);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return mapModels;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Service returing correct values, but I don't even have idea how to use them.
I installed Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.Clustering and tried to find some good step by step tutorial but didn't find anything useful. Many tutorials are about Xamarin.Android.
I'm using MVVM pattern.
[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the sample app for the package?  All it appears to do  is call Map.Cluster();  after the pins are added

Comment: @Jason This one: [link](https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps) ?
I'm trying to figure it out even how to set pins on the map. I using clustering for the first time now... On what should I foucus on at the link?

Comment: https://github.com/mierzynskim/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.Clustering/blob/master/Sample/XFGoogleMapSample/ClusterPage.xaml.cs

Answer (score 0):

this a link [how to use Maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map)in Xamarin.Forms

1.install the **Xamarin.Forms.Maps** NuGet package

2.`Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init` method is required in each application project

3.Platform configuration (refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map#platform-configuration))

4.as you get the postion from service ,so after you get the correct values,you could do like this:

```
//new Position(37,-122) is your postion center
var map = new Map(
 MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(37,-122), Distance.FromMiles(0.3))) {
            IsShowingUser = true,
            HeightRequest = 100,
            WidthRequest = 960,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
        };
    var stack = new StackLayout { Spacing = 0 };
    stack.Children.Add(map);
    Content = stack;
```

if you want add pin to the map,you could use

```
var position = new Position(37,-122); // Latitude, Longitude
var pin = new Pin {
        Type = PinType.Place,
        Position = position,
        Label = "custom pin",
        Address = "custom detail info"
    };
map.Pins.Add(pin);
```

Comment: I geting 'Map' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments error. Where should add yout parts of code?

Comment: I aded image of tha page where is map. So I have home page with three tabs and tab Map shoul show map (like on image) but with pins.

Comment: have you install the NugetPackage？

Comment: Yes I installed.

Comment: @NitrusBrio not 1 arguments,it needs 2 arguments

Comment: Thank's for asking. :)
I successfully added pins and polygons using Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps instead of Xamarin.Forms.Maps on my colleague recomendation. But I still have problem to cluster them. I installed Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.Clustering but I don't know how to use it propertly.
I tried to folow this example:
https://github.com/mierzynskim/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps.Clustering
but can't even run it.